# Hibernate JPA CriteriaQuery ParameterExpression<Collection> used multiple times - NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

After migration to Hibernate 6, using `ParameterExpression` with the `Collection` type leads to `NoSuchElementException`. It seems that there is an `Iterator` created for each parameter and something tries to go through it multiple times. It was working in the previous versions of Hibernate. A very dummy query as an example:

```
public List<Long> example(Long userId) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> query = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<User> user = query.from(User.class);
    query.select(user.get(User_.id));
    ParameterExpression<Collection<Long>> userIdParam = builder.parameter(generify(Collection.class));
    query.where(
            builder.or(
                    user.get(User_.id).in(userIdParam),
                    user.get(User_.id).in(userIdParam)
            )
    );
    query.distinct(true);
    TypedQuery<Long> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
    typedQuery.setParameter(userIdParam, Collections.singletonList(userId));
    return typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

It's a bit cumbersome to create N identical parameter expressions one for each condition. Any advice?

Stacktrace:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at java.util.Collections$1.next(Collections.java:4817) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmUtil.createJdbcParameterBindings(SqmUtil.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.buildCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:358) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:268) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:518) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:367) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor137.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:405) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at jdk.proxy3.$Proxy156.getResultList(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.example.dao.UserDao.example(UserDao.java:265) ~[example-dao-3.22.1.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at com.example.dao.UserDao$$SpringCGLIB$$0.example(<generated>) ~[example-dao-3.22.1.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior is deliberately introduced to manifest probable logical mistakes in queries. In your demo example you join two same predicates with `or` which is obviously misuse.

Then imagine the case you receive a collection of `ids` as method parameter and you use it in two different predicates. I agree that in some cases this could be a valid behavior and programmer's intention, but in most cases I guess this would be a mistake and `NSEE` at least draws developer's attention to the query.

Comment: As I wrote it's just a dummy example, don't expect I will put a real one from a commercial code ;)

Comment: Sure, I understand, this is just my speculation about why the Hibernate behaves in this way. Could you put stack trace, at least its part as of JPA infrastructure